# How to increase the speed of crawling in Apify?

Tags: apify

I am using Apify and the speed of crawling is horrible. I need to go through approx 12,500 of pages of property listings.

Starting page:
https://www.sreality.cz/hledani/prodej/byty?strana=1

Link selector:
a[href]

Pseudo-URLs:
https://www.sreality.cz/detail/prodej/byt/[.+]/[.+]/[.+]
https://www.sreality.cz/hledani/prodej/byty?strana=[.+]

The first is detail of a apartment
The second is next pages

My Page function:

async function pageFunction(context) {

```
const { request, log, skipLinks, jQuery: $, waitFor } = context;
const pageTitle = $('title').first().text();

context.log.info(`URL: ${context.request.url}, TITLE: ${pageTitle}`);

if (request.userData.label === 'DETAIL') {
return {
    url: context.request.url,
    pageTitle,
    name: $('span.name.ng-binding').eq(3).text(),
    };

}
```

}

Right now I am only scraping the name. I want to solve the speed first.

Thanks for any answers :)

Comment: How much memory are you using? What performance results are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're using **Web Scraper** (https://apify.com/apify/web-scraper) which uses the Chromium browser. In this case, the speed is affected by many factors including the run memory setting, loading resources process, and the required time for rendering the data. Please check the limitations section here for more info: https://apify.com/apify/web-scraper#limitations

You can try **Cheerio Scraper** (https://apify.com/apify/cheerio-scraper) for its high performance and if that didn't work you can try **Puppeteer Scraper** (https://apify.com/apify/puppeteer-scraper) which give you more control on the scraping process (e.g blocking unnecessary resources).